# Issue with Mac Safari using jQuery Selectbox Plugin

Tags: jquery, css, macos, safari, drop-down-menu

On the website I'm working on we are using the jQuery selectbox plugin but are resizing one of them to fit the content (from 120px to 200px).

However when using Safari on Mac the CSS does not take affect so we attempted to override this using jQuery, but this does not work either. jQuery does not see the element in the DOM until I use the inspect element option, which then renders the ability to test useless.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a fix?

Thanks.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").selectbox("attach");
    $("#playerScroll, .playerScroll").scrollbars();
    $("#playerScroll, .playerScroll").mousewheel(function(event,delta){});
    $("#playerTransfers .filter li:nth-child(4) .sbHolder").css('width','200px');
});
```

CSS:

```
#playerTransfers .filter li:nth-child(4) .sbOptions,
#playerTransfers .filter li:nth-child(4) .sbHolder,
#playerTransfers2 .filter li:nth-child(4) .sbHolder,
#playerTransfers2 .filter li:nth-child(4) .sbOptions,
#playerTransfer .filter li:nth-child(4) .sbSelector{
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: Paste some code... add a jsfiddle... Do something :)

Comment: Code added to original post